# extract values of column according to value in another columns in csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, parsing, dictionary-comprehension

Here is my file:

```
 id;verbatim;score
0;1; je suis beau;1
1;2; je suis laid;0
2;3;je suis merveilleux;1
3;4;je suis repugne;0
```

I would like to extract all sentences in column "verbatim" which have a score of 1 and all which have a score of 0 so that I have two separated files:

```
print(verbatim, score = 1)
id;verbatim;score
1; je suis beau;1
3;je suis merveilleux;1
```

and

```
print(verbatim, score = 0)
id;verbatim;score
2; je suis laid;0
4;je suis repugne;0
```

I started to write some code but I do not really think it is on the right path:

```
df = pd.read_csv("out.csv", na_values = ['no info', '.'], encoding='latin-    1', delimiter=';')    
m1 = df['verbatim'].eq(0)
m2 = df['critere'].eq(0)


SizePos = df[m1 & m2]
dSizeZero_PptPosf2 = df[m1 & ~m2]
SizeZero_PptZero = df[~m1]

print(SizePos)
```

When i print df.head() after reading the file I have :

```
      id                                           Verbatim   ...    Scoreneg  Scoreneu
   0   1  Je nai pas bien compris si cétait destiné à ...   ...           6813     3202
   1   2  Peut-être quil faut que je révise mes classiq...   ...       20842     3974
   2   3  ça peut donner une photographie pour dire que ...   ...        5083      384
   3   4  Je comprends bien lintérêt quil peut y avoir...   ...       11335     1132
   4   5         Jai bien compris le concept, cest clair.   ...         258       91
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("out.csv", na_values = ['no info', '.'], encoding='latin-    1', delimiter=';')    

df[df['score'] == 1].to_csv("score1.csv")
df[df['score'] == 0].to_csv("score0.csv")
```

As simple as that.

Comment: thank you but it is not working. It is the same content.

Comment: I put the result in my question see above:

Comment: i tried this df0[df0['Niveau'] == 1]['Verbatim'].to_csv('Niveau1.csv', sep=';', encoding='latin-1') and it works like this :  0;Je n’ai pas bien compris si c’était destiné à rester ad-vitam dans le bâtiment ou si c’est juste à la livraison sur une période donnée. Parce que si c’et un bâtiment neuf, sauf à dire qu’il y a des malfaçons… j’ai du mal à comprendre
1;Peut-être qu’il faut que je révise mes classiques mais le R est calculé au vu des différents composants de la paroi et il ne peut pas évoluer comme ça à la minute     ,   ----I would like to print also the column id, Can you help me ?

Comment: If it works then try: `df0[df0['Niveau'] == 1][['Verbatim', 'id']].to_csv('Niveau1.csv', sep=';', encoding='latin-1')`

Answer (score 2):

If you intend on using `pd.read_csv()`, and you are interested in extracting just the sentences that meet your desired criteria, then you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=';')

df[df['score']==1]['verbatim'].values

df[df['score']==0]['verbatim'].values
```

This would give:

```
[' je suis beau' 'je suis merveilleux']
[' je suis laid' 'je suis repugne']
```

Comment: thank you it is working but how can i print it in a new file : i tried this but it is nit what i want , it prints also the score  :  df0[df0['score'] == 0]['verbatim'].to_csv('score0.csv', sep=';', encoding='latin-1') => I just want the list of the verbatim in the csv file as output , do you have an idea ?